# How can I get out of all loops after I find my item(link) in table

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

Project table contains project list project has columns (Id, name,  PM, etc. ) when clicking on a project, Project details page opens for the project. the Automation find the project and click on it  but I get this error

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference
>   of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM,
>   it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been
>   refreshed

I think after clicking on the project, after going to the Proj detail page, the loop doesn't stop. how can I break; from all the loops after I find my project 
I am new to automation I need help

```
public static void SelectProject()
{
    IWebElement Table = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("projectsGrid"));
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> allRows = Table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
    foreach (IWebElement row in allRows)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> cells = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
        {
            if (cell.Text.Contains("002032"))
            {
                cell.Click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either with a flag or a Goto.

Comment: In this case it seems like you could just use `return`.

Answer (score 2):

No need for flags, use return instead of break.

```
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally try to avoid break statements, so I would try and use a while or for with a sentinel value but if you want to use foreach you should include a bool that decides whether you break for each loop.  Once you find what you want then set the bool.  For example:

```
public static void SelectProject()
{
    IWebElement Table = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("projectsGrid"));
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> allRows = 
        Table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

    bool loop = true;

    foreach (IWebElement row in allRows)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> cells = 
            row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
        {
            if (cell.Text.Contains("002032"))
        {
            cell.Click();
            loop = false;
        }
             if (!loop)
             break;
        }
        if (!loop)
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of 99% of the logic in this function with a good locator.

```
public void SelectProject()
{
    Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("[@id='projectsGrid']//td[.='002032']")).Click();
}
```

The above method with throw an exception if this element doesn't exist. Your current method won't do anything (throw an exception or click an element) if the element doesn't exist. If you want that behavior, use the code below.

```
public void SelectProject()
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> e = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("[@id='projectsGrid']//td[.='002032']"));
    if (e.Any())
    {
        e.ElementAt(0).Click();
    }
}
```